# Reducing overfitting in CNN by increasing training data size versus augmenting images (preprocessing data) using DataImageGenerator

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Does increasing the size of the training data helps in reducing overfitting ? Or is it suggested to go for image augmentation (data preprocessing) using the ImageDataGenerator in Tensorflow to skew or rotate the image to decrease overfitting ? 
Which method is better to reduce overfitting ??

Answer (score 0):

By means of image augmentation, basically you are increasing the size of your training data. If you have data which is different from your existing training data, then adding that data into your training data is good.

So in short, both the methods are good to overcome over-fitting.